# Inner Join based on column value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, inner-join

I would like to join two tables based on a column value

- if `pm.ServiceLevelID` value is 1 or `NULL` then inner join on `u.FacilityId`
- if `pm.ServiceLevelID` value is 2 then inner join on `u.FacilityServiceId`

These two tables `pm, u` have these columns:

```
ProviderMessages
  MessageID, FacilityServiceID, ServiceLevelID, FacilityID, ProviderTypeID

User_FA
  FacilityServiceId, UserFacilityID, FacilityId
```

Currently, I have this `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MessageID, UserFacilityID, 9    
FROM 
    #ProviderMessages   
INNER JOIN 
    #User_FA ON (#User_FA.FacilityId = #ProviderMessages.FacilityID OR  
                                   #ProviderMessages.FacilityID IS NULL)
             AND (#User_FA.FacilityServiceId = #ProviderMessages.FacilityServiceID)
```

Comment: use [Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: I am wondering what's so bad about this question. -5, really?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT MessageID, UserFacilityID, 9    
 FROM #ProviderMessages   
 JOIN #User_FA 
   ON #ProviderMessages.ServiceLevelID  in (null,1,2) 
  and (  ( #ProviderMessages.ServiceLevelID  in (null,1) 
           and #User_FA.FacilityId = #ProviderMessages.FacilityID) 
         or 
         ( ProviderMessages.ServiceLevelID = 2
           AND #User_FA.FacilityServiceId = #ProviderMessages.FacilityServiceID) 
      )
```

Comment: what's the advantage to adding the clause `#ProviderMessages,ServiceLevelID  in (null,1,2) 
  and`?

Comment: @Beth I don't think it could hurt.  And I think it lets the query optimizer throw stuff out early.

Comment: guess it depends on the scale.  I doubt there's any other values, though.

Comment: @Beth Why guess?  Check the query plan.  It is either going to do an index seek early on ServiceLevelID or not.  A faster query is not of value?

Answer (score -1):

This is your query, with table aliases to make it more readable:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MessageID, UserFacilityID, 9    
FROM #ProviderMessages m INNER JOI
     #User_FA u
    ON (u.FacilityId = m.FacilityID OR m.FacilityID IS NULL) AND
       u.FacilityServiceId = m.FacilityServiceID;
```

The logic you want is

```
SELECT DISTINCT MessageID, UserFacilityID, 9    
FROM #ProviderMessages m INNER JOIN
     #User_FA u
    ON ((pm.ServiceLevelID = 1 or pm.ServiceLevelID is null) AND pm.FacilityId = u.facilityId) or
       (pm.ServiceLevelID = 2 and pm.FacilityServiceID = m.FacilityServiceID)
```

Comment: How is the output wrong?  That is what you are asking for.

Comment: What is the output, and what were you expecting it to be?  A simple  "it isn't what I wanted" doesn't help anyone get after the solution you're really after.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understood well, but in my previous job we had similar situations.
Please try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MessageID, UserFacilityID, 9    
FROM 
    #ProviderMessages   
    INNER JOIN #User_FA 
        ON (CASE WHEN ISNULL(#ProviderMessages.ServiceLevelID, 1) = 1
                 THEN #ProviderMessages.FacilityID
                 ELSE #ProviderMessages.FacilityServiceId
            END)
            = (CASE WHEN ISNULL(#ProviderMessages.ServiceLevelID, 1) = 1
                 THEN #User_FA.FacilityId
                 ELSE #User_FA.FacilityServiceId
              END)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Union the two results

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT MessageID, UserFacilityID, 9    
FROM #ProviderMessages   
INNER JOIN #User_FA ON (#User_FA.FacilityId = #ProviderMessages.FacilityID OR  
                                   #ProviderMessages.FacilityID IS NULL)
WHERE #ProviderMessages.ServiceLevel <> 2

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT MessageID, UserFacilityID, 9    
FROM #ProviderMessages   
INNER JOIN #User_FA ON (#User_FA.FacilityServiceId = #ProviderMessages.FacilityServiceID)
WHERE #ProviderMessages.ServiceLevel = 2
```